# How to send Array to a text box with Python selenium scripting?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, selenium

The code which i have written to send the an array list to a text-box in my internal site. Where the input to array is from excel.

```
value = [] // ArrayList
while len(value)<1000:
    Data=sheet.row(loop)
    T1 = Data[1].value
    T2=int(T1) // to remove float values
    T2 = str(T2) // as the text-box is only accepting the strings
    value.append(T2)
    loop += 1 //to read the next row in the excel sheet.
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="operand.action_(id=7)"]').send_keys(values[0:])
```

Format of values sending to text-box is: ['40554666', '40554539', '40554762', '40554806']

This is giving me an error because the above code is sending the values to the text-box in a wrong format where i need to remove " '' " and " [] " The Text-box can only take the numbers separated by comma or numbers in new line.

Note : I have tried to send one element at a time but that is not effective solution for my site. That is the reason i am trying to send 1k values at a time.

Can someone please help me here ?

Comment: It looks to me like you need to [format your string](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting).

Comment: Can we use formatting in send_keys() function??

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your comment and becoz of it an idea strikes to my mind to resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's what an array of string looks like when you print the array itself in python. You need to loop through the array use one element at a time.

```
mylist = ['1','2','3']
print(mylist)
```

This prints `['1', '2', '3']`

You want

```
for list_item in mylist:
    print(list_item)
```

and that prints

```
1
2
3
```

More specifically

```
for list_item in mylist:
    ...
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="operand.action_(id=7)"]').send_keys(list_item)
```

Side note: If all you are using is the ID, why use XPath? Just use

```
driver.find_element_by_id('operand.action_(id=7)')
```

Comment: The looping I have tried already and it is not effective n slow for my website. That is the reason i am trying to send 1k values at a time. Is there any way to send formated values of array to the texbox??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do... you are trying to send a comma-delimited list of the array elements? e.g. if the array is `['1','2','3']` you want to send what? `1,2,3`?

Comment: Yes, i am able to achieve it by using join. Here is the details:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="operand.action_(id=7)"]').send_keys(','.join(value))

But getting an error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to convert data to an object

Can you please help me here to understand why i am getting this error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Run `test = ','.join(value)` and see what goes into `test`. Make sure it's `1,2,3` or whatever like you expect. It sounds like it's not.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Somehow after a restart it started working fine. I am really Thank you for your time and response.